# Listview onclick method crashes when no URL links

Tags: android, listview, url

Hello i have a listview filled with data when some of this data contains a URL link i want to be able to click and open the browser.
I managed to do so with the following code :

```
          mylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
          int position, long id) {

            if(Links[position]!= " ")
            {
              startActivity(new Intent(
             Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(Links[position])));
            }
          }
      });
```

And by adding  :

```
   android:autoLink="web"
   android:linksClickable="true"
```

to my xml.

I know that when my links array does not have a URl it is equal to " ".
My problem is the parts of the listview without a URL leads the app to crash when clicked. So the URL works fine but i want nothing to happen when a part of the listview without a url is clicked.
Any thoughts?

```
03-19 14:03:30.264: D/TextView(19847): onTouchEvent - action: 0, mEditor:      null, mMovement: null
03-19 14:03:30.414: D/AndroidRuntime(19847): Shutting down VM
03-19 14:03:30.414: W/dalvikvm(19847): threadid=1: thread exiting with     uncaught exception (group=0x41592898)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=  }
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at com.example.corneforum.Threadactivity$1.onItemClick(Threadactivity.java:72)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:744)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-19 14:03:30.434: E/AndroidRuntime(19847):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

added crash log

Comment: Please post your crash log.

Comment: i think your App crashed because you try to get url with position out of bound Links array. check position < Links.size() before try to access this

Answer (score 0):

use Try/Catch like this:

```
try {
    statements you want to do; //such as clicking button
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "no URL found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

you can find the right exception you want. example: NumbeFormatException is for avoiding crash when entered a string instead of number.

Comment: yeah thats right. but when you dont have any URL what you want to do when clicked the button?

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! I want nothing to happen when i dont have a URL.

Comment: @JonhSmith anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i have wasted your time it was always going inside the if statement which is obvious from the log. I apologize.
Something like

```
if(Links[position].contains("http"));
```

Fixed my problem.
Thanks for your help.